# How to extract all occurrences within quotes from string to array?

Tags: php

I have string like this:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:12:"Text One";i:1;s:16:"Text Two";i:2;s:14:"Text Three";}
```

I want to extract all occurrences within quotes to array. For example the result i want from above string should be:

```
array["text One", "Text Two", "Text Three"]
```

How can I achieve this with as little code as possible?

Comment: how about you just use `unserialize()`?

Comment: What did you try to achieve your goal?

Comment: I see, it's not valid serialized data.  Maybe that's just sample data?

Comment: I think either it's json encoded value or serialized value. so just use unserealize or json_decode and it will automatically comes out an array.

Comment: It looks like corrupted [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data (the string length counts are off). otherwise you could just `unserialize` just like @AbraCadaver said

Comment: @AbraCadaver ! Thanks for such a quick response :) it really saved me time and yes it did work.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach to your problem depends on your specific needs (see the comments).. but to just answer your question directly:

```
$str = 'a:3:{i:0;s:12:"Text One";i:1;s:16:"Text Two";i:2;s:14:"Text Three";}';
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```